# compress Images dynamically in python Flask

Tags: python, flask, image-compression

I am trying to reduce(compress) image file size dynamically.

Reason being I need it dynamically, because I need to use it in full size as well on another pages.(Hence I cant make any changes to original images at server)
The project I'm working on is like blog post. on main page there are few featured_post which contains image and post data. when we clicked on the post, it will in full where the post image will load in in background and on main page it acts like a thumbnail

issue: on main page when images load into the featured_post it should load in reduced size than original to finish the loading of page quick
Note : at least 20 featured_post per page

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you generate all the needed sizes and resolutions when saving a blog post - not on the fly. Obviously for performance reasons.

For image manipulation in Python I recommend you to use the `pillow` library:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/